# How to set discount value in Quick Book?

Tags: ruby, quickbooks

I am trying to apply discount value in Quick book but for some reason discount does not apply in Quickbook. Can you please guide me how can i resolve this issue?

```
https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/issues/267
```

Discount value code:

```
              discount_amount = discount_value
              discount_line_item = Quickbooks::Model::InvoiceLineItem.new
              discount_line_item.amount = discount_amount#149
              discount_line_item.discount_item! do |detail|
                detail.discount_account_id = 48
              end

Discount percentage code:

discount_line_item = Quickbooks::Model::InvoiceLineItem.new
              discount_line_item.amount = discount_percentage_value#149
              discount_line_item.discount_item! do |detail|
                detail.discount_percent = discount_percentage_value#60
                detail.percent_based = percent_based
                detail.discount_account_id = 48
end
 invoice.line_items << discount_line_item
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a google search and fount [this link](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/issues/216) that may be useful in solving your issue. Otherwise, there's no way we can help you; is the application timing out, is the data not being posted to quickbooks, is there an error in your log file?